# QML Mac fullscreen mode lose mouse focus

Tags: macos, qt, qml, fullscreen

I'm using QML to build an OSX application with fullscreen mode support. My intention is to toggle fullscreen/normal mode by double-clicking the main area of the window, here is the minimal code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 800; height: 480
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.WindowFullscreenButtonHint // for OSX native behavior support

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked: {
            if (main.visibility === Window.FullScreen) {
                main.visibility = Window.AutomaticVisibility;
            } else {
                main.visibility = Window.FullScreen;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's very simple, but the behavior is weird:

Whenever the *visibility* state of the application changes(enter or leave), the user **must click in the window one more time** before the window mode can change again, just like **the application loses the mouse focus**.

To validate what I'm thinking, I test something more, I add one more `MouseArea`(let's say `mouseAreaTest`) in the window, which split the window side by side and can receive `onEntered` and `onExited` event. Right after the application *enter* or *exit* fullscreen mode, `mouseAreaTest` will never receive any Enter or Exit event, unless you click on the window **one more time**, which is not what I want.

I know nothing about how OSX implement its own fullscreen mode, nor why QML on OSX has such a buggy problem. So I expect someone will tell me something about it.

---

**Update**

Later I doubted if this was only something about QML which related something about the Window System of QML, so I tried using **traditional `QtWidgets`**, and found the **same result** there.

---

**Update**

I tracked the mouse event of traditional widget, and found the problem: the double click event consisted of two click event(press-release-press-release), when the window state changd(fullscreen to normal or normal to fullscreen), **the last RELEASE event will never be received UNLESS click one more time**.

I also did more test: use a button to control window state, and the problem is gone, so I may probably consider this is a bug of mouse event handle.

---

By the way, post system info for a note:

OSX 10.10.1
Qt 5.4.1

Comment: That's probably not related to QML but really to the containing window (that's why also widgets behave the same way). I've tested the code on my OS X box and on a Windows machine: the latter works perfectly fine. IMO firing a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) could be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I tested on Windows too, it worked with no problem, I would fire a bug to qt.io later.

Comment: Any updating? I also encounter this problem on OSX 10.11.5 with Qt 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

This bug still exists in Qt 5.11. I found a workaround eventually.

The reason why the last mouse release event not received is that we toggled fullscreen **immediately**. Somehow the mouse release event was lost during transition to fullscreen.

So the fix was simple: **we postpone toggling fullscreen till next mouse release event**. i.e. when we need to toggle fullscreen, set a flag temporarily, then in mouseReleaseEvent, check the flag and do the real work.